# is it possible to retrieve all userID from firebase at one time?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a sets of data in firebase database and I wanted to retrieve all the userID, but not its content, just a list of userID will do. Anyone has done it before?

Comment: Yes, it has been done before. However, we don't know your platform, your Firebase structure or what a userID is exactly. You need to clarify your question and provide enough data for us to answer. Please take a moment and review [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In what platform are you referring to? Assuming you are talking about java you can do something like that:

```
     usersDatabaseRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override 
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for(Datasnapshot snap2 : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                   String userId = snap2.getKey();
                }
            } 

            @Override 
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            } 
        });
```

Comment: sorry forgot :)